# Split multiple hive queries if query contains a semicolon

Tags: regex, scala, split

I am trying to split multiple hive queries in files, and loop over them and run them using scala/spark. I am using `.split(";")`. But it is creating a problem when the query itself has a semicolon.

```
select * from table where value='myName\;is\;Name';
select * from table;
```

How can I escape the semicolon in the first query and split the above into 2 separate queries in scala

Comment: Does each statement on a new line? If so, you can split by "\n"

Comment: I am not sure like the query file is by user so it can be anything not necessary will be on new line

Comment: So, you mean you want to split only ; and skip the \;

Comment: If you have no single quotes inside the queries, and if they are always paired, and if the queries are not that huge you may use `.split(";(?=(?:[^']'[^']*')*[^']*$)")` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/dB1uQ9/1)). Else, write your own parser.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why the query size matters in regex, is it because of performance issue ?

Comment: Since regex engine checks each `;`, after which there is a lookahead check, yes, I think it might be not that safe to use that regex above (from the efficiency perspective).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, helped
 me :)

Answer (score 0):

Let check this pattern:

```
.split("(?<!\\\\);")
```

In Java, it return a correct output, but I am not sure it work for you on Scala.

The pattern mean: Find the ; with not \ before. 
You can find "Negative look behind" regex for more detail.

Comment: This works great if the user has escaped the ; by himself, but is there anyway if the queries are like
<br>
`select * from table where value='myName;is;Name';
select * from table;`

Comment: Then, I think you have to define  a rule to recognize them. Find one main difference between them: inline semicolon vs semicolon at the end of line, escape semicolon vs normal semicolon, semicolon follow by 'select' vs semicolon follow by none 'query'... It's must base on your real context.